# Letting evil >> increment org level

Tags: org-mode, evil, indentation

In evil mode, `>>` increments the indentation level of the current line.
It does so at an org heading too, even though it would be more
appropriate there if it would increase the org level (the number of
stars).  I realize that I could, for instance, redefine the function to
which `>>` is bound to check if point is at an org heading and if so
take the appropriate alternative action.  But I suspect this would not
be the most correct way of doing it.  What would?